What would be the impact of Direct Taxes on the National Income of a country?
Consider a simple closed economic system $(Y = C + I + G)$ such that $C = c (Y-DT)$; $I = i(r)$. Now consider that Total Taxes $(TT)$ is given as $TT = DT + IDT$, where, $DT$ = direct tax and $IDT$ is Indirect Taxes. Assume a case where $DT = t(Y)$ and IDT = $d(C)$. Derive the multipliers. Also, check what would be the impact of $DT$ on $dY$ by taking various ratios. Based on this you should write a report on what will be the impact of abolition of Direct Taxes in India. Also, keep in mind that the complete abolition of Direct taxes would have an impact on $G$ as in the absence of $DT$ the debt of the government would increase if the decrease in $DT$ is not compensated by an increase in C leading to an increase in $IDT$.
